# Current sensing, low pass filter and ADC frequency

Tags: adc, low-power, control

I am designing the circuit that will read the current in a DC motor. The PWM on the H bridge will be running at 10/15 KHz with an ADC sampling frequency and a control loop running at ~ 5KHz. I will have to check the R/L constants of the motors to make sure the control frequency is suitable. For now the proposed the circuit is showed below.

Initially I was planning on using a low pass filter before the ADC pin of the PIC. However I have read a few contradicting threads on whether i should or should not use a low pass before the ADC of the PIC. I read a few Application notes all promoting the use of the filters. Should I use an anti aliasing filter here?

If the filter is needed would you able able to comment on the cut-off frequency to use? The cut off frequency of the Sallen Key below is around 2.5 KHz. (1/2 the intended sampling rate of the ADC).

I would also be curious to see if someone could comment on C9 below. I saw a few schematics using a small ceramic capacitor placed there so i decided to use one too. Not sure about its real purpose to be honest.

[image: Schematics]

Comment: you need another resistor equal in value to R7 from +ve amp input to GND to complete your attempt at a differntial amplifier

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself is: do you want digitized aliased high frequency noise or not?

Comment: Your schematic uses an unreadable font, I honestly can't tell which one is C9. Is it the 22µF or 10nF?

Comment: 27pF but i saw values ranging from ~20pF to ~60pF

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use an anti aliasing filter here?

I think you should. In some applications they are omitted because the system is intentionally trying to sample signals beyond the Nyquist rate of the ADC. I can't think of a reason not to use one. If you know of a good reason, please share.

> I would also be curious to see if someone could comment on C9 below.

It seems to be nothing more than a low-pass filter (along wtih R5 and R6) to reject high frequency noise coming from the source before it gets amplified by the first stage amplifier. I think it is a good idea to put the cutoff of this filter at a reasonable frequency. If you are using the ADC as part of a feedback system, that might be 10x the sample rate.

Answer (score 1):

C9 appears to be nothing more than a filter used to reduce high frequency noise due to the motor from being passed along and amplified/processed with the signal.